# Cargar cada select de opciones por aparte y enviar el parámetro

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Actualmente tengo una función que me recorre toda una tabla y envía el valor de cada celda a PHP por medio de un Ajax. Pero en este caso cuando recorre y captura lo de la celda donde hay un select, se mandan todas las opciones del mismo y no la seleccionada. Este fue el código que hice en JS.

```js
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnCopiar').click(function(){
   document.getElementById("btnCopiar").disabled=true; // Envita el doble envío por el docente
alert("Se está registrando la asistencia en Zeus por favor espere....");

  $('#milista tr').each(function () { // For each recorre cada alumno y su condición en la clase
     
    var nombre= $(this).find('.docenter').text();
    var usuario = $(this).find('.usuarior').text(); // Aquí se envian los tres valores del SELECT
    var correo = $(this).find('.correor').text();

  $.ajax({
    
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "RegistrarA.php",
     data: "nombre=" + nombre + "&usuario=" + usuario + "&correo=" + correo,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data !== "");  
                        
      }
    });   
    });

alert("Los Registros ya fueron enviados ¡Gracias!");

   });
});
</script>
```

Este es el código del HTML que utilizo en dónde aparece el  y el

```html
<td class='usuarior' id='datoa' contenteditable='true' width=\"4%\">" . '<center><select id ="comboa" class ="condiciona" type="text">

     <option value="Presente">Presente</option>
     <option value="Ausente">Ausente</option>
     <option value="Au. Justificada">Au. Justificada</option>
    </select></center>'
        . "</font></td>
```

Resultado en la base de datosw.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia este selector, que literalmente esta jalando el texto completo de la celda.

```javascript
var usuario = $(this).find('.usuarior').text();
```

Por este para que busque el valor seleccionado de la lista

```javascript
var usuario = $(this).find('.usuarior option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Muchisímas gracias por tu ayuda, era lo que necesitaba...